# Do spritekit menu area and buttons need to be part of the scene?

Tags: uiview, sprite-kit, skscene

Trying to code my first sprite kit game. At the top of the screen I will have a menu area, that will have buttons, game time, etc. The game's `skscene` will be positioned directly below.  Both will be visible at the same time.

Since the menu is just a menu, my idea is to make that area a `UIView` with ordinary `UIButtons`, i.e. no sprite kit nodes.  Then, below the menu, add an `SKView`, have it fill the remainder of the screen and present the game scene.  So the menu area is a `UIView`, and the game area is a sibling `SKView`.

Is this best practice? From many of the examples I come across, it feels like sprite kit intends you to have just one SKView, and present the scene full screen, and include any menu buttons inside the scene itself as sprite nodes. But I don't see the advantage in doing it like that.

Comment: the advantage is that everything is integrated together through spriteKit. The biggest disadvantage I think of your way is having to pass data constantly between UI elements and SpriteKit elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many games, the "main menu" you describe would be called an "HUD," or Heads Up Display. It shows all the buttons that you require and is simply a SKSpriteNode at the top of your screen. You can add SKSpriteNodes as child nodes of the HUD that, when tapped, will perform an action:

```
    let button = SKSpriteNode()
    button.position = CGPointMake((-200), 0)
    button.color = SKColor.redColor()
    button.size = CGSizeMake(15, 15)
    button.name = "button"
    HUD.addChild(button)
```

Check if that button was pressed:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
        if node.name = "button" {
            //run code
        }
    }
}
```

This method is fairly easy, but you have to give up UIButtons. You also will probably want to design the nodes you will use as buttons: I used [this](https://sketch.io/sketchpad/) editor.

Hope this helped and good luck.

Comment: Thanks that editor looks nifty. I'm not saying menus can't be done with spritekit - ppl do it all the time - it just seems more work than using `UIView` stuff.  But yes, I can see that if you want to do more customizable things, or have the buttons overlap other elements of the scene, then this is the better way.

Comment: In retrospect my question was kind of vague, so this answer is acceptable.

Comment: I like that simple answer, and the designer is a true bonus! Thanks!